# Force WordPress to always redirect to custom location after login, even if redirect_to is already set

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a server running WordPress 4.9.9 and PHP 7.2.

I am trying to redirect users after they log in.

To achieve this I am doing essentially this:

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return '/new-dashboard-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

It works great when you log in on this URL:

`/wp-login.php`

It does not work if `redirect_to` is already set in the query string:

`/wp-login.php?redirect_to=some-place`

I also tried the `wp_login` hook just in case but that doesn't even fire if `redirect_to` is set in the query string.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'admin_default_page');
```

How can I get WordPress to always redirect to `/new-dashboard-url` after login, regardless of what may or may not be set in the query string.

At the moment I am hacking my way around it by redirecting the login page to self if `redirect_to` is set in the query string to strip it out, but to my mind that's just that - a hack.

I can't help but think that both `login_redirect` and `wp_login` worked regardless of `redirect_to` being set.

Did the behaviour of these hooks change recently or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: my guess is that, you should add priority to your filter, and parameters to your function.

Comment: Just tested on a clean install and it worked fine for me. Maybe a theme/plugin is overriding this? If it is, you can always try adding a high priority to your filter, i.e. `add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page',9999]);`

Comment: like : `add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'admin_default_page', 30, 3 );` and `function admin_default_page($redirect_to, $request, $user ) {` -- not sure though

Comment: @Stender The parameters won't make any difference as they're not used in the filter.

Comment: if you can find the current redirect function - you can remove the filter first

Comment: @markmoxx - I wasn't sure, if the function had to accept all three parameters to be called by the filter. thats why i added it.

Comment: but if this is working in a clean install - it might be a priority issue.

Comment: Priority seems to have no effect but thanks for checking it on a clean install @markmoxx - that confirms at least that something is indeed interfering. I'll leave this open for now in case I do find what's messing with it.